# How to click buttons after creating with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 10 buttons that are created when click button "Create".

How to also click all those buttons when i click "Create" ?

```
function a() {
    selectAll();
    jQuery(selectAllValues());
};

function selectAllValues() {
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("select" + array[i]).click();
    }
};
```

The problem is that the buttons are created but not clicked.

Comment: In `selectAllValues` function, you are using a variable `array` which is not existing (almost in this context)

Comment: I didnt paste all the code. The buttons appear ok, but they are not clicked. If i run the click button event after from the console they trigger as they supposed to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use Jquery like this :

```
$("#select" + array[i]).click();
```

Or without loop : http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

```
//Will execute the click event on all element where the id begins by "select"
$('[id^="select"]').click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to click them all? Are these actually checkboxes that you are trying to mark as "Checked"?

```
//If checkboxes then try
$('#select'+array[i]).prop('checked', true);
```

if these are truly buttons then why wouldn't you manually initialize the "onClick" function that they would initialize?

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    //call the onClick function yourself here
}
```

Please elaborate

EDIT:

```
function selectAllValues() {
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        $('#select'+array[i]).prop('checked', true);

        //code to create tables

        //loop through tables
        $('tableselector').each(function(key,value){
            //check the checkboxes within the tables
            $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Exactly, they are checkboxes, that when I click a button, each checkbox creates a table with a button. Then I want that button to be clicked. The event is to select all the values in the table. +1 for reading my mind

Comment: I am literally confused more now LOL, but this sounds intense! I will edit my main post once I can wrap my mind around this.

Comment: Ok. I will elaborate: I have 10 checkboxes that are false. And 1 button A. When I click button A all those checkboxes are checked. When each checkbox is checked it appends a table + a button. That button when clicked selects some values. What I want is when I click button A  (the main button) all the checkboxes get checked, then all the values from each created table get selected.

Comment: The problem is that right now when i click button A the checkboxes are checked but those buttons do not trigger. After the page is loaded I can trigger all of them from the console, so probably the problem is the way the page loads.

Comment: It sounds quite complex, I would imagine you need to figure out some sort of looping algorithm to keep calling stuff manually because I have honestly never been able to emulate a literal "Click" as if the user did it. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful!